# Filter rows in Excel file by specific words

Tags: python, excel, search

I have been struggling to devise a python code that will search for 'N' words in an excel file. And where any of the 'N' words exist, the python code should output the entire row in which these words exist. I am searching for multiple word occurrences in an excel file.

Assume an excel file of this type(say it is called `File.xlsx`):

```
ID    Date        Time      Comment
123   12/23/2017  11:10:02 Trouble with pin
98y   01/17/2016  12:45:01 Great web experience. But I had some issues.
76H   05/39/2017  09:55:59 Could not log into the portal.
```

The question, in light of the above data is:
If I were to search for words, 'pin' and 'log' and find it in the above excel file, I want my python code to output line1 and below it, output line3.

Conceptually, I can think of ways to solve this, but the Python implementation befuddles me. Furthermore, I have extensively searched in Stack Overflow but could not find a post that addressed this question.

Any and all help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Start with one of the python packages here: http://www.python-excel.org/. Since you only want to *read* the excel file (not writing excel files), you could use [xlrd](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Are you wanting to update the contents of `File.xlsx`, create a filtered file e.g. `filtered.xlsx` or just display the required rows?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could accomplish this, as there are many python packages to read Excel files (http://www.python-excel.org/), but [xlrd](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) may be the most straightfoward way:

```
import xlrd                             # package to read Excel file

book = xlrd.open_workbook("File.xls")   # open the file
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)             # get first Excel sheet

words = ['pin', 'log']                  # list of words to search

for rx in xrange(sh.nrows):             # for each row in file
    for word in words:                  # for each word in list
        if word in str(sh.row(rx)):     # check of word in row
            print 'line',rx             # if so, print row number
```

outputs:

```
line 1
line 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) module which I've been using successfully for many projects.

row index starts from one including headers , hence if you dont want to count headers , we will need to reduce index count by 1 `row - 1`

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'afile.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
search_words = ['pin' , 'log']

for row in xrange(1,ws.max_row + 1):
    for col in xrange(1,ws.max_column + 1):
        _cell = ws.cell(row=row, column=col)
        if any(word in str(_cell.value) for word in search_words):
            print "line {}".format(row - 1)
            break
>>> 
line 1
line 3
```

If you want to output actual lines then
Just add following `print_row` function

```
def print_row(row):
    line = ''
    for col in xrange(1,ws.max_column + 1):
        _cell = ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value
        if _cell:
            line += ' ' + str(_cell)
    return line
```

And replace `print "line {}".format(row - 1)` with `print print_row(row)`

```
>>> 
 123 2017-12-23 00:00:00 11:10:02 Trouble with pin
 76H 05/39/2017 09:55:59 Could not log into the portal.
>>>
```